# Check null parameter in painless - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

How are we supposed to check whether a key in map passed as parameter to a painless script has a value? I am currently doing this in Elasticsearch 6.8.4

```
if (params.feedId!=null) {
    whatever()
}
```

but it throws this exception when

> params.feedId

is null

```
ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=Cannot cast null to a primitive type [void].]]
```

It works fine with Elasticsearch 5.6.13, so there seems to be a breaking change but I couldn't find anything so far.

**UPDATE:** It was actually not a problem with this part of the script but in some parts of it we were doing *return null;* to break the process of the script, which does not seem to be working anymore for some reason. To give more context, I am doing those updates using the Java API, more specifically the Rest High Level client.

I have been able to reproduce the issue using a curl command like this

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/myindex/_doc/1/_update?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
        "script": {
                "source": "ctx._source.result = true; return null;" 
        }
}'
```

This produces the next output:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "remote_transport_exception",
        "reason" : "[sBix--f][172.18.0.4:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to execute script",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "script_exception",
      "reason" : "compile error",
      "script_stack" : [
        "... ce.result = true; return null;",
        "                             ^---- HERE"
      ],
      "script" : "ctx._source.result = true; return null;",
      "lang" : "painless",
      "caused_by" : {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Cannot cast null to a primitive type [void]."
      }
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Just replacing *return null;* for *return;* makes this script working fine in ES 6.8.4.

Found this issue at Elasticsearch: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/35888. There are some inconsistencies in the way short-circuit works in different versions of Elasticsearch.

Comment: Can you please share you query?

Comment: Please show the full query.

Comment: I have updated the issue description. Thanks for your interest!